# Why does getAllResponseHeaders() output differ from what the browser sees?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have a simple bit of code with which I'm trying to read some headers off a URL response:

```
$.ajax(manifestAnchor.href, {
    type: "HEAD"
}).done((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
    console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
});
```

Which, in my test case outputs the following:

`date: Wed, 13 Sep 2017 09:44:15 GMT
content-type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
cache-control: no-cache`

However when inspecting the response in the browser, I see a different set of headers:

[image]

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser restricts your frontend JavaScript code to only being able to access the `Cache-Control`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Type`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, and `Pragma` response headers, unless the response has an `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header that lists other header names that the browser should also expose.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

In the case of the response shown in the question, the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date` response header tells the browser to also expose the `Date` header. Therefore your code is able to get that header. But that `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header doesn’t list the `Server`, `Accept-Ranges`, or `Content-Length` header names. So your code isn’t able to get those.

And again, your browser is what’s preventing your code from getting at those. The browser itself gets all the response headers, and that’s why you can see them in browser devtools. But just because you can see them there don’t mean the browser will expose them to your code; the browser will only expose what the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header tells it to expose.